# Compare long value with int/long zero constant

Tags: c#, optimization

Is this:

```
if (myLongValue > 0) // 0 is displayed as int in Visual Studio tooltip
```

equal to:

```
if (myLongValue > 0L)
```

and is this using special opcode? (something like JZ - jump if zero in x86 asm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2 are perfectly equivalent in terms of IL. Let's take for example the following code snippet:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    long myLongValue = long.Parse("123");
    if (myLongValue > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ok");
    }
}
```

It gets compiled to the following IL (in Release mode):

```
.method public hidebysig static void Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] int64 myLongValue)
    L_0000: ldstr "123"
    L_0005: call int64 [mscorlib]System.Int64::Parse(string)
    L_000a: stloc.0 
    L_000b: ldloc.0 
    L_000c: ldc.i4.0 
    L_000d: conv.i8 
    L_000e: ble.s L_001a
    L_0010: ldstr "ok"
    L_0015: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    L_001a: ret 
}
```

Now replace `if (myLongValue > 0)` with `if (myLongValue > 0L)` and you get strictly equivalent IL.

A more optimal IL would have been this but unfortunately I am unable to make the compiler emit it:

```
.method public hidebysig static void Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] int64 myLongValue)
    L_0000: ldstr "123"
    L_0005: call int64 [mscorlib]System.Int64::Parse(string)
    L_000a: stloc.0 
    L_000b: ldloc.0 
    L_000c: ldc.i8.0 
    L_000d: ble.s L_001a
    L_0010: ldstr "ok"
    L_0015: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    L_001a: ret 
}
```

Here we don't need a `conv.i8` instruction because we have directly pushed the supplied value of type Int64 onto the evaluation stack as an int64.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, the operator `>` has a left-hand side which is `long` (`System.Int64`) and a right-hand side which is `int` (`System.Int32`). Since the C# specification does not define an *overload* of the `>` operator with that signature, we have to check if some conversion applies to one (or both) of the arguments (operands).

There exists an *implicit* conversion from `int` to `long`. The conversion in the other direction is not implicit. Therefore the right-hand side gets converted by a widening conversion, and the overload `operator >(long x, long y)` is used.

Since in this case, the right-hand side `int` is a compile-time *literal*, the compiler can do the widening of the constant, and so there's no difference between your two examples after compilation. Another answer has demonstrated what the output IL looks like.

So what if instead you had:

```
ulong myULongValue = XXX;
if (myULongValue > 0)
    ...
```

In general, there's no *implicit* conversion from `int` (signed) to `ulong` (unsigned). However, when the `int` is a compile-time constant (literal) that happens to be non-negative, there does exist a conversion. So my example above still works (and produces the same as `if (myULongValue > 0ul)`).

But for non-constant `int`, it has to fail:

```
ulong myULongValue = XXX;
int zero = 0;               // not const
if (myULongValue > zero)    // will NOT compile!
    ...
```